# Vue JS v-attr=“expression1 && exp2 && exp3” are not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue JS `v-attr=“expression1 && exp2 && exp3”` are not working. I am also tried `${&}${&}` and like `#{&}#{&}` and `&amp;&amp;` and also like `#{&amp;}#{&amp;}`

Code is available in JSFiddle

```
<div id="demo">
 <button v-for="item in itemlist" :disabled="item.qty < 1 && item.qty < 9">Click</button>
</div>    


var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    title: 'itemlist',
    itemlist: [
        {
            qty: 0
        },
        {
            qty: 10
        },
        {
            qty: 6
        }
    ]
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3330/

Comment: what is the problem? Your check is just false. Check that the object is < 1 and < 9 ? you might want to check if it's greater than 1 ? http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3331/

Comment: the first item is less than 1 and less than 9 => disabled = true; the others evaluate to false 10 <1 = false , 10 <9 = false=> false&&false == false, 6 <1 = false,  6 <9 = true ==> false && true = false

Comment: Thanks @CodeHacker my expression is mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your intention was

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-for="item in itemlist" :disabled="item.qty >= 1 && item.qty <= 9">Click</button>
</div>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3333/)